# Typescript compiling errors using 'vss-web-extension-sdk' & 'azure-pipelines-task-lib'

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to follow the following guide to make a custom task in azure devops https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops

When I install both 'azure-pipelines-task-lib' & 'vss-web-extension-sdk'
and have a single typescript file that requires the task-lib, like the guide suggests, I get tons of typescript errors.

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "azure-pipelines-task-lib": "^3.1.9",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
    "vss-web-extension-sdk": "^5.141.0"
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",
        "rootDir": "src/",
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "types": [
            "vss-web-extension-sdk"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "src/index.ts"
    ]
}
```

index.ts

```
import tl = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/task');

export function Foo() {
    return "BAR"
}
```

File structure

> - Root
>
>   - tsconfig.json
>   - package.json
>   - src
>
>     - index.ts
>   - dist
>
>     - index.js

Errors

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOTrn.jpg

```
node_modules/@types/node/module.d.ts:2:5 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'mod'.

2     export = NodeJS.Module;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/requirejs/index.d.ts:38:14
    38     export = mod;
                    ~~~
    'mod' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/requirejs/index.d.ts:38:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'mod'.

38     export = mod;
                ~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/module.d.ts:2:5
    2     export = NodeJS.Module;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'mod' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/requirejs/index.d.ts:422:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 
'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'.

422 declare var require: Require;
                ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:213:13
    213 declare var require: NodeRequire;
                    ~~~~~~~
    'require' was also declared here.

node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/vss.d.ts:3168:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'.

3168 declare var require: Require;
                 ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:213:13
    213 declare var require: NodeRequire;
                    ~~~~~~~
    'require' was also declared here.
```

Can someone provide me with ANY working example of compiling typescript when these libraries are installed?